# What is the dpkg equivalent of "rpm -i"?

Tags: rpm, dpkg

I have a package installed on an Ubuntu machine, and I need to list the metadata of that installed package to determine where it came from.

On a Redhat based machine, "rpm -i [packagename]" will give me the information I need. What is the equivalent dpkg command to do this?

Comment: apt-cache show is my best proposition... but I don't see a good equivalent. Once more rpm is far better :)

Answer (score 0):

dpkg-query gives you all information about packages. Simply 'dpkg -p ' gives info like 'rpm -qi '. Also '--showformat' can format output in view which you want.